# Find overlapping circles in Java

Tags: java, geometry, overlapping, points

is there a simple way to find overlapping circles (each with one point in the middle and the same radius) in Java?

For example, if I have a dataset and I have those points

```
Point1 (3|3)
Point2 (4|2)
r = 1
```

So I will have it like this:

[image: Overlapping Points]

How can I check in Java, whether those two points are overlapping?

Best and thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to determine whether two points are distance `2r` away from each other?

Comment: Are the centers at unit coordinates and the radii one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circles overlap if the distance between the centers is less than the sum of the radii:

```
public static boolean checkOverlap(Circle c1, Circle c2) {
    return Math.hypot(c1.x - c2.x, c1.y - c2.y) < c1.r + c2.r;
}
```

If you have many circles and are looking for pairwise overlaps, you might be able to use a [*k*-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to do better than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `<=` operator? It seems to me that a point in `(0,1)` is contained in both circles centered on `(0,0)` an `(0,2)`, and with a radius of 1.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Depends on if you're considering the sets to be open or closed. OP hasn't specified anything about this, but it's an easy change in any case.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually just a matter of applying the Pythagorean theorem.

```
boolean areCirclesOverlappint(Point a, Point b, double radius) {
    double diffX = a.x - b.x;
    double diffY = a.y - b.y;
    return diffX * diffX + diffY * diffy <= radius * radius * 4;
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. I believe that that's the standard representation in English.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't know the English name, so be my guest!

Comment: You knew it well enough to where I was afraid of being unnecessarily pedantic.

Comment: I believe you need a square root on the LHS or squares on the RHS

Answer (score 2):

**A simple heuristic**. (This is just an addition to arshajii's answer.)

If you want to avoid the k-D tree, you can sort the centers on their X coordinate. Then consider all circles in turn, and check overlap only with those having a center abscissa in [X,X+2R].

Assuming N circles uniformly spread in a domain of relative size M (side over diameter), you will trade N²/2 comparisons for max(N²/M, N) only.